# Complex Numbers Questions...

Tags: complex-numbers

I am having trouble with these problems:

1. Find all complex numbers $z$ satisfying the equation
   $$\frac{z+1}{z-1} = i.$$
2. The value
   $$\left(\frac{1+\sqrt 3}{2\sqrt 2}+\frac{\sqrt 3-1}{2\sqrt 2}i\right)^{72}$$
   is a positive real number. What real number is it?

On 1) , I was thinking about substituting $z$ for $a+bi$ and then solving. Is this correct?

Comment: For 1) it is right your thought

Comment: For 1), ask yourself how you would solve the equation $\frac{x+1}{x-1}=3$; you'll need to use some real number arithmetic. Then follow the same procedure for $\frac{z+1}{z-1}=i$; you'll need to use some complex number arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

Put one question for each thread please. For number 1, you have
$$
i=1+\frac{2}{z-1} \implies z=1+\frac{2}{i-1}=-i.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**For the first**:

We have $$i = 1 + \frac{2}{z-1} \Rightarrow z= -i$$

**For the second**:

We can write $$\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \cos 60^\circ \cos 45^\circ +\sin 60^\circ \sin 45^\circ = \cos (60^\circ -45^\circ ) = \cos 15^\circ$$ Similarly, we have, $\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}} = \sin 15^\circ$. Thus, using [De Moivre's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula), we get, $$(\cos 15^\circ + \sin 15^\circ )^{72} = (\cos 1080^\circ + \sin 1080^\circ) = (\cos 6\pi + \sin 6\pi) = 1$$   Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For 1 just use simple arithmetic: it's a degree one equation.

For 2, compute first the square:
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{1+\sqrt 3}{2\sqrt 2}+\frac{\sqrt 3-1}{2\sqrt 2}i\right)^{2}
&=
\left(\frac{1+\sqrt 3}{2\sqrt 2}\right)^2-
\left(\frac{\sqrt 3-1}{2\sqrt 2}\right)^2+
2\frac{1+\sqrt 3}{2\sqrt 2}\frac{\sqrt 3-1}{2\sqrt 2}i
\\[6px]
&=\frac{1+3+2\sqrt{3}}{8}-\frac{3+1-2\sqrt{3}}{8}+
2\frac{3-1}{8}i
\\[6px]
&=
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i
\\[6px]
&=\cos\frac{\pi}{6}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{6}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**hint for the first**

Your equation can be written as

$$\frac{z-1+2}{z-1}=1+\frac{2}{z-1}=i$$

$$\implies z-1=\frac{2}{(i-1)}=-(i+1)$$

$$\implies z=-i$$

Comment: It is not just a hint:-))))...but it is right;-)